# Can't catch class derived from std::exception by reference to std::exception

Tags: c++, exception, polymorphism

I created a custom exception class that derives from std::exception.

```
#include <iostream>

class Exception : std::exception {
public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return "test";
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw Exception();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This program, when compiled by `g++ -stdc++=17` on Ubuntu, causes the exception to not get caught by the `catch` block, even though catching by reference is supposed to catch derived exceptions too. It calls `std::terminate`, even though it happens in a `try` block that catches its base class by reference. Same thing happens if `Exception` inherits from `std::runtime_error` and passes `"test"` to the `std::runtime_error` constructor in its own constructor. Normally the solution would be to only catch using `Exception`, but in my original code I need to catch different types of exceptions, all of which inherit from `std::exception`. Why does this happen? Does catching by reference to base not work? How can I catch all exceptions deriving from `std::exception` using one catch block?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you inherit from a base class during the definition of a `class`, the default access modifier for the inheritance is `private`. This means that the two following definitions are equivalent:

```
class derived : base { /* ... */ };
class derived : private base { /* ... */ };
```

The language doesn't allow<sup>1</sup> you to refer to a derived class from a private base<sup>2</sup>. As an example, the following code does not compile:

```
int main()
{
    derived d;
    base& b = d; // <== compilation error
}
```

> ```
> error: 'base' is an inaccessible base of 'derived'
>      base& b = d;
>                ^
> ```
>
> [**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SmMSGbvXMteiAZxu)

---

This is the reason why your `catch` block cannot handle `Exception`. Change your inheritance to `public`...

```
class Exception : public std::exception
```

...and your original code will work.

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NwaYdrmZmTQIXRTs)

---

<sup>1</sup> See [[dcl.init.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#:assignment,reference) and [[conv.ptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.ptr#3).

<sup>2</sup> Unless you're in the scope of `derived` itself. See this [**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zLWDfLXyDa1qxK0U).

Comment: It is also possible to catch an `Exception` as a `std::exception` from a `friend` of `derived`.

Comment: @Peter possible in friend, yes, but not in derived. Inheritance would need to be at least protected for that.

Comment: Nice answer +10.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to publicly derive from `std::exception`

```
class Exception : public std::exception
```

Then your [output](http://cpp.sh/8qz4d) is

```
test
```

For more details about this topic, please reference [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance).

Comment: Would be nice to explain why this doesn't work with private inheritance